# how to append and remove child div in parent div on button click?

Tags: angular, typescript

i have been searching for ways to to add and remove divs on add button remove button click.

i tried adding using *ngFor but instead i want to append Div Chunk

how can i do that? help me with this.

```
//Html code that i want to add to parent div on add button click...
      <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Example name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="***" placeholder="" required>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Example date</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" formControlName="**" placeholder="" required>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Example issuing agency</label>
            <select class="form-control" formControlName="**">
              <option>agency</option>
              <option>agency</option>
            </select>
           </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just toggle the div style from display: block; to display: none;?

Comment: there is no fixed length of divs to add for showing and hiding it. So, im looking for dynamic div insert with unique id assigned to it.

Comment: What you can try to do is dynamically assign ID's with an incrimination for each one (ID1, ID2..) and append the parent div to add them in with each create button click. I'm not sure exactly how you want your website to function ,but for removing the DIV you could simply add an onclick function to the entry's DIV and then change the display to none. If you REALLY want to change the actual HTML then for each DIV you create, you can save it in an array, and when you want to remove one you can empty the main parent div and then repopulate it with all the DIV's in the array except the removed one.

Answer (score 0):

As Gregory Bond said you can use CSS to with the display property toggled or you can use JS to add and remove nodes with a function.

if you are new to CSS I would recommend writing your own and not using any framework like bootstrap it makes it easier in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making that block of html it's own component. Where it would take some kind of model as it's input.

If you are only ever wanting to show one, then ngif would make sense to use, toggling display on a Boolean controlled by the button.

If you want to have multiple, then use an ngfor and append an empty input model to the array when the button is pressed